# “The data area passed to a system call is too small” error when Windows Store app after installing with more than 8GB memory in use

Tags: windows, installation, windows-store

###### Steps to reproduce

1. Reboot PC and sign in (Windows 10)
2. Run apps such that your total memory usage exceeds 8 GB. For me this is either Visual Studio, Chrome, VSCode etc (with Docker and SQLServer running in the background), OR simply running "testlimit -d -c 4096" (using [testlimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit) from Sysinternals)
3. Try to install something from the Windows Store (e.g. Slack). I'm not sure whether the app needs to be a Desktop Bridge app or whether the problem exists for UWP apps too. It doesn't seem to matter whether the app comes directly from Windows Store or whether it's a sideloaded .appx

###### Expected result

Application launches and runs.

###### Actual result

Application fails with the message:

> The data area passed to a system call is too small.

---

My question is: can anyone suggest how I can troubleshoot that error to find the underlying cause?
Also, can anyone else reproduce this same issue? I'm interested whether it's something specific to my PC or whether it's a problem with the Windows Store in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an incompatibility issue with MS SQL Server 2017 (and 2014/2016). If possible uninstall SQL Server. Otherwise these patches can solve the issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073393/fix-the-data-area-passed-to-a-system-call-is-too-small-error-when-you

If you use it just for dev purpose, it's possible to run in a Docker container instead, which runs isolated enough to prevent this error. I have very good experience running SQL Server 2017 for Linux, which is stable and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue with Windows Subsystem for Linux when trying to launch Ubuntu.  For me, it's not memory related, I can try to launch Ubuntu as soon as my machine reboots and I log on and still get the error.

I think in my case it actually has to do with having a network home drive and enabling offline files on that drive.

I can install a fresh version of Windows 10, install and configure WSL and Ubuntu, run it for weeks without enabling offline files and it works fine.  Once I enable offline files and reboot Ubuntu will no longer launch and gives the "data area too small" error message.  Disabling offline files for the home drive and even disabling offline files completely doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  So the only workaround I've found is to never enable offline files on my home drive.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue ("The data area passed to a system call is too small") in windows 10,  Due to this issue i couldn't able to open Skype. After some analysis there is issue in Microsoft SQL Server drivers.

To resolve the issue,
I disabled skype from startup in Task manager (Skype only got affect to me). then i restart the system and after reboot the system then open the skype its working fine